# limit the points is showed in x-axis of plotly.js

Tags: plotly

I have plotly.js graph with data:

```
TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');

Plotly.plot( TESTER, [
    {
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
    }
]);
```

example: [codepen](http://codepen.io/plotly/pen/PPVeer)

I want to limit the points is showed in x-axis is 3 points and when using "PAN" will see other points.

ex:
[image]

[image]

Please help me! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the range of your Xaxis. By default it shows all data.

```
Plotly.plot( TESTER, [{
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16] }], { 
    margin: { t: 0 }, xaxis:{ range:[1,3] } } );
```